# How to display a system tray icon in Ubuntu 20.04+?

Tags: system-tray

I write an application for myself and want to display a system tray icon - at the top right - in it. Is there a library I can use? The application is in .NET core, so any library that can be easily invoked from there would be preferred.

I already looked into `libappindicator`, which is currently my best bet, but its description says it's for Unity. I also looked into GTK, but its status icon widget is deprecated.

Can somebody confirm that `libappindicator` also works for newer Gnome versions of Ubuntu or are there any other recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

`libayatana-appindicator3` works for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Some API samples:

https://github.com/getlantern/systray/blob/master/systray_linux.c

https://github.com/purejava/appindicator-gtk3-java/wiki